# indexOf on CharSequence implementations that support it

Tags: java, oop, indexof

In my program I use a lot of Strings and StringBuilders. I would like to get rid of the StringBuilder toString() method and use CharSequences throughout. However I need access to the indexOf method (which is available in both StringBuilder and String but not in other implementations). How might I implement an interface that will make this function visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could do it reasonably easily by hardcoding tests for known types, and doing it "manually" otherwise:

```
public static int indexOf(CharSequence input, String needle) {
    if (input instanceof String) {
        String text = (String) input;
        return text.indexOf(needle);
    }
    if (input instanceof StringBuilder) {
        StringBuilder text = (StringBuilder) input;
        return text.indexOf(needle);
    }
    // TODO: Do this without calling toString() :)
    return input.toString().indexOf(needle);
}
```

This is pretty ugly in terms of hard-coding the types, but it'll work.

Comment: I guessed that what I would have to do, I just thought it was ugly as well and wondered if there was a different way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the default method from [TextUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html): [indexOf](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#indexOf(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Where is class `TextUtils`, i.e.: which `import` is needed?

Comment: `import android.text.TextUtils;`

Comment: Please keep in mind that not all java programs are Android apps.

Answer (score -1):

One thought is to have a class with multiple static implementations for each type.

```
public class Strings{

    public static int indexOf(String input, String c){
        return input.indexOf(c);
    }

    public static int indexOf(StringBuilder input, String c){
        return input.indexOf(c);
    }

    public static int indexOf(YourClass input, String c){
        return input.indexOf(c);
    }
}
```

This way, you can just call `Strings.indexOf(whatever)` for each type that has an implementation. Which will keep your code clean by letting the compiler/jvm pick which method to use for you.

Comment: If `input` has `YourClass` type, and there is no `indexOf()` for it, how does this help (third case)?

Comment: This only works if the concrete type is known (and used) at build time. If at build time the only thing you know is that it is some CharSequence implementation, overloads won't help you and you will have to use instanceof, like the Jon Skeet's answer does.